# How to spell buggz

Tags: language

My lizard is named Booger,  for short I call them "b-ugz" but how do I spell it in English?
I don't know what kind of question you really want to rephrase it as, I thought my first sentence summed it up well.

Comment: Please try [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer: You decide

Longer answer: What language does the lizard speak? How does it sound in lizard language? Is the lizard willing to let English speakers use some substitute for his real name?

I will give you example on myself. My name is `Pavel Janíček` which is "normal" [Czech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_language)  name. However, I know by meeting several English speaking only people, that such name is really hard to pronounce in English.

So, usually I go by telling people that they can call me Paul, which is closest English synonyme for the first name, and I let them pronounce my surname as it is written without any diacrititcs.

The morale of the story is, that the lizard can either go by let himself be called just "Buzz" which would be easily to prononce for any English speaker, or insist that his name is pronounced ... Well, you decide.

Comment: I knew the lizards have to do with this,perhaps B̛̖͔̗̻ͅu̹g̹̦g҉̼̙̞̗̞̤z̦͔̼̟̪?